# NSUserDefault issues. save/retrieve data including a UIImageView grid[][]

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to save information in a game but I got stuck.

I tried a different approach before trying with NSUserDefault.

What I'm trying to save is

*PlayerScore  //NSInteger

*HighScore //NSInteger

*Level //NSInteger

*Time //int

*The button settings on SFX and background music

*The background musics position, so it will resume where it stopped

*the grid which is the gamefield and the bricks upon it (the grid is 6x6 and is also a UIImageView *grid[][] type, the bricks on it are 35)

```
-(void)saveGameState {

NSLog(@"saveGameState");
NSLog(@"totalrubies %d", totalrubies);
NSLog(@"playerscore %d", playerscore);
NSLog(@"highscore %d", highscore);
NSLog(@"level %d", level);
NSLog(@"totalseconds %d", totalSeconds);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalrubies forKey:kRubiesKey]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:playerscore forKey:kPScoreKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highscore forKey:kHScoreKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:level forKey:kLevelKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalSeconds forKey:kTimeKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


for (int y = 0; y < BRICKHEIGHT; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < BRICKWIDTH; x++) 
    {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:grid[x][y] forKey:kGridKey];
        NSLog(@"grid[BRICKWIDTH][BRICKHEIGHT] %d", grid[x][y].tag);
    }
}
```

}

I tried this way also

`NSData *ImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (grid[x][y]);
                      [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ImageData forKey:kGridKey];`

but then I got an warning: **incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIImageView *', expected 'struct UIImage *' when passing argument 1 of 'UIImagePNGRepresentation' from distinct Objective-C type**

I have managed, I think, to save everything except the last 3 * in the list. I need help with those specially with the grid part, that's prio 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` the `UIImage` in the `UIImageView`, hence this error message.

Try :

```
UIImageView *imgView = grid[x][y];
NSData *ImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgView.image);
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ImageData forKey:kGridKey];
```

Comment: ok? I thought I did when I tried this part... NSData *ImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (grid[x][y]); [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ImageData forKey:kGridKey];

Comment: Nice... the warning disappeared. how do I load it back in? like this grid[x][y] = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ObjectforKey:kGridKey]; ?

Comment: no, because `grid[x][y]` is actually a `UIImageView`, not a `UIIamge`.

Comment: I load it back like this right? grid[x][y] = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ObjectforKey:kGridKey];

Comment: you must put every `NSData`instance in an array before, and then setting the array as the value for your key, because this way a each turn, you will put **another** value in place of the previous one. So to load the array back : `NSArray *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectforKey:kGridKey];`. As your grid is 6x6, you should have 36 `NSData` objects, load them back using the same double loop, increment a simple counter ;). At each turn : `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageData objectAtIndex:i]];`

Comment: I'll give it a try... thanks... is there a way to get hold of you in case I need more help? ps. shall I create 36 NSData objects in the savegamestate AND the loadgamestate or just in the loadgamestate?

Comment: you are welcome, if my answer fits your needs, consider clicking on the checkmark on the left ;)

Comment: shall I create 36 NSData objects in the savegamestate AND the loadgamestate or just in the loadgamestate?

Comment: if your need is storing the images data into `NSUserDefaults`, and your grid is 6x6, running a double loop this way will result in storing, yes, 36 `NSData` objects. This way you store them whenever you need, and load them back later. Have a look @Jim's answer too...

Comment: @iphonedevonthemake let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1536/discussion-between-vince-and-iphonedevonthemake)

Comment: are you there Vince? I'm in the chat but it looks like I'm the only one

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is not really a great solution for this.  Have you considered CoreData or the filesystem?

Saving the images themselves seems unnecessary and wasteful.  All you have to do is record the state of the game - i.e. which brick is in which position.  You should be able to recreate the view from that data easily.

Comment: I tried with CoreData first but got the information from another forum that NSUserDefaults was a better solution then CoreData.